# Write NAN (from C++ code) to sql server 2012

Tags: c++11, sql-server-2012, oledb

I have a `float, null` parameter in a DB table.
From my C++11 application, I want to write `nan` value to DB table as `NULL`.

I am doing following:
1. Converting `nan` to `L"NULL"` and store in `CComBSTR`
2. In DB, converting this string back to `NULL` and write this against `float` column.

**My question:** any better way of writing `nan` to DB in this case?
Specifically I want to avoid this `CComBstr` conversion as frequency of updates are quiet high and using many float parameters in table.

Comment: And why you want to change it if it works? The conversion does not seem a bottleneck to me, at least compared to the database insertion that is usually slow compared to in-memory pc c++ operations..

Comment: yes, its not bottleneck for functionality, but my concern is performance, I am casting from nan to string, and then string back to NULL in DB. Also have to reserve some size in DB for string.

Comment: I was talking about performances. performing a query to a db is much slower than performing some casting operations, so if they are correct, and it seems so, the performance loss is irrelevant and spending time and effort to trying to optimize it is probably useless. It's like trying to save one second in a two-second operations while the next one takes five minutes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got another solution which looks better than this, so thought to share this:
There are multiple macros used for reading/writing data from DB like `COLUMN_ENTRY_STATUS`, `COLUMN_ENTRY_TYPE_STATUS` etc...

These takes `status` flag for each DB field.
-While writing, if value is `NAN`, set `status` flag to `DBSTATUS_S_ISNULL`, DB itself will set `float` field value to `NULL`.
-While reading if `status` flag is `DBSTATUS_S_ISNULL` set value to `NAN`.